# Put variables into Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge

Example I have a letter. I have to address it to 10 people. Each of the 10 people will have a unique info which I'll need to input in.

So it's like Dear X, Check out Y!

I'll like to pull the info from a list like, X: John/Peter/Jack. Y: SiteA/SiteB/SiteC

It'll create 3 files in this case,
1st: Dear John, check out SiteA!
2nd: Dear Peter, check out SiteB!
3rd: Dear Jack, check out SiteC!

It'll be in a Word Doc. Any ideas? 
(Objective is to print them out individually)

Comment: You can use the Mail Merge functionality built-in to Microsoft Word. However, this is not a programming question, so I am voting to move it to SuperUser.com.

Answer (score 0):

Yes mail merge is the perfect canditate to achieve this sort of thing. Check out [the tutorial](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/word-mail-merge-a-walk-through-the-process-HA001034920.aspx) on the Office site.